# Commands for Websphere MQ instead of using Websphere MQ Explorer

Tags: ibm-mq

I am facing this issue  with IBM Websphere MQ v7.5 on Unix : [WebSphere 7, configuring JMS Q connection factory without user id: MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012579/websphere-7-configuring-jms-q-connection-factory-without-user-id-mqrc-not-auth)

As mentioned in the link, I need to set the user ID to mqm in WAS admin panel. I can't have any GUI support on my system. Is there a way to do this by some commands ?

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: When you say you don't have any GUI on your system, do you mean you don't have access to the WAS admin panel? If yes, suggest you add tags for WAS to this question as you need help from WAS experts. If no, please explain which GUI you mean as your title suggests MQ commands and the MQ Explorer, but your question doesn't indicate what it is you want to change in MQ, only something in WAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, but if you are looking to change the MCA user on the server connection channel of the QM used by WAS, then you can do the following on the MQ server.

Start MQ command line console:

```
runmqsc <QM name>
```

In the MQ console:

```
alter channel(<name of the channel>) chltype(SVRCONN) mcauser(<the user to be used for all connections on this channel>)
```